How exactly do we go from an indefinite to a definite property at measurement in quantum mechanics?
I’m terribly confused on how this process happens. In entanglement, suppose we are making a measurement on the spin of an electron. From Alice’s perspective, the spin could either be up or down. Alice then observes that the spin is up.
How does it go from an indefinite spin that can be represented as (0,1) to (1)?
